# download pdf from google sheet and

Tags: google-apps-script

I found this code where I can download google sheet to pdf but I want to change it in order to chose another sheet then the active one and download the pdf once the code run without the box.

```html
function PDF() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetId = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/a/mydomain.org/spreadsheets/d/" + ss.getId() + "/export?exportFormat=pdf&gid=" + sheetId + "&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var str = '<input type="button" value="Download" onClick="location.href=\'' + url + '\'" >';
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(str);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Download_Report");
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I want to change it in order to chose another sheet then the active one and download the pdf once the code run without the box.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: What I meant is I want to run this code on a sheet other then the one I am currently using

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

From `What I meant is I want to run this code on a sheet other then the one I am currently using`, for example, if you want to use `sheetId` of other sheet except for the active sheet, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var sheetId = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
```

#### To:

When you want to use the sheet name, please modify as follows.

```
var sheetId = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getSheetId(); // Please set the sheet name like "Sheet2".
```

When you want to use the index of the sheet, please modify as follows. In this case, `index = 1` is the 2nd sheet. So, the 1st sheet index is `0`.

```
var index = 1; // Please set the index of the sheet you want to use.
var sheetId = ss.getSheets()[index].getSheetId();
```

- Of cource, you can directly put the specific sheet ID you want to use.

#### References:

- [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
- [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)